# Redirect from subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, vhosts

Sorry for asking such a (probably) simple question:

I want to redirect http://blog.mysite.loc  and   http://blog.mysite.loc/blog to  http://mysite.loc/blog.

The following rule is added in the Apache vhost file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://goempiremovers.loc/blog$1 [L,R=301]
```

With this, http://blog.mysite.loc/blog will point to http://mysite.loc/blog/blog.

What rule can I add to fix this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to redirect http://blog.mysite.loc and
>   http://blog.mysite.loc/blog to http://mysite.loc/blog.

You could redirect *everything* from `blog` subdomain to `mysite.loc` (main domain)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog/)?(.*)$ http://mysite.loc/blog/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. The problem is that, using this rule, blog.mysite.loc/blog/ will redirect to mysite.loc/blog/blog/(and this is not ok, it should go to mysite.loc/blog).

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that case. I edited my answer, should be ok now